# Vector2.MoveTowards в корутине

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Суть: 2D бесконечный раннер, игрок не успел среагировать, препятствие "отодвинуло" персонажа. И дабы всю игру персонаж не бежал где-то сбоку, через время возвращать его назад на середину экран, тобеж на нулевую координату по X. У препятствий тег "Barrier". По коду, приведенному ниже, ничего не происходит. Сама корутина запускается (проверено посредством Debug.Log), а MoveTowards не срабатывает. Скрипт висит на персонаже.

```
public float returnSpeed;

[SerializeField] private Transform target;

public void Start()
{
    target = transform;
    target.position = new Vector2(0f, 0f);
}

public void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Barrier") && (transform.position.x < 0))
    {
        StartCoroutine("ReturnPositionToZero");
    }
}

private IEnumerator ReturnPositionToZero()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    var step = returnSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. returnSpeed Нигде не инициализирован и равен нулю,  а значит и step == 0.
2. ReturnPositionToZero Выполнится всего один раз через 3 секунды и движение может быть незаметно(зависит от returnSpeed).

Нужно примерно так:

```
returnSpeed = 5;// подбери нужное число
private IEnumerator ReturnPositionToZero()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);//хз зачем
    int iteration = 0;// просто что бы случайно не уйти в бесконечный 
цикл(тогда редактор просто зависнет, а игра упадет)
    float  delta = 0.1f;// или любая дельта
    while (Vector2.Distance(transform.position,target.position) > delta && iteration < 100)
    {
        iteration++;
        var step = returnSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();//ждем конца кадра
    }
 
  
}
```

Немного ссылок:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForEndOfFrame.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Distance.html

Comment: Спасибо, сразу не срабатывало правда. Но сделал target не Transform'ом, а Vector2 и все работает. Только персонаж очень сильно дергается при возвращении в нулевую координату

Comment: Дергается - измени returnSpeed